# Is there a way for me to distribute points so that they're more compact near a different set of points?

Tags: processing, typography, voronoi

I want to make a Voronoi tiling which fits itself to some text in Processing 3.5.3. I've got the algorithm for standard Voronoi tiling implemented, but I initialise all points to just be randomly distributed across the window.
I've got a list of points which make up some letters, generated by the `geomerative` package. They're all in the standard `(x, y)` format.

I'm looking for a function which would take the text points and the window size into account and give me back a sort of distribution, or, better yet, a list of points already following that distribution.

My code:

```java
import geomerative.*;

public class Point {
  public RPoint p = new RPoint(0, 0);;
  public color c;
  public boolean isTextPt;
  
  public Point(int _w, int _h, float[][] distribution) {
    
    
    
    
    
    this.p.x = random(_w);
    this.p.y = random(_h);
    //this.c = color(random(100, 250), random(100, 250), random(100, 250));
    this.c = color(map(p.x, 0, _w, 50, 160), map(p.y, 0, _h, 0, 150), 255);
    this.isTextPt = false;
  }
  
  public Point(float _x, float _y) {
    this.p.x = _x;
    this.p.y = _y;
    this.c = color(random(50, 160), random(100, 250), 255);
    this.isTextPt = true;
  }
}

int baseAmountOfCells = 50;

RShape shape;
RPoint[] textPts;
Point[] points;

void setup() {
  RG.init(this);
  shape = new RFont("RobotoMono-Medium.ttf", 140, RFont.CENTER).toShape("voronoi songs for worley days");
  textPts = shape.getPoints();
  
  fullScreen();
  colorMode(HSB);
  
  points = new Point[baseAmountOfCells + textPts.length];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < baseAmountOfCells; i ++) {
    points[i] = new Point(width, height);
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < textPts.length; i ++) {
    points[baseAmountOfCells + i] = new Point(textPts[i].x / 2 + width / 2, textPts[i].y / 2 + height / 2);
  }
  
  println("Amount of text points: " + str(textPts.length));
  
  
}

void draw() {
  loadPixels();
  int index = 0;
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      float record = width * height; //it can never be more than this
      int recIndex = 0;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        float d = dist(x, y, points[i].p.x, points[i].p.y);
        if (d < record) {
          record = d;
          recIndex = i;
        }
      }
      
      Point pt = points[recIndex];
 
      pixels[index] = color(pt.c);
      index++;
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
  
  for (Point pt : points) {
    if (pt.isTextPt) {
      stroke(0);
      strokeWeight(2);
      point(pt.p.x, pt.p.y);
    }
  }
  
 noLoop();
}
```

Comment: "take the text points and the window size into account and give me back a sort of distribution" I think you need to explain much more about what you mean.

Comment: @micycle fair point, I didn't really explain it well. I want it to be a sort of elliptical gradient going from the center of the text point as white, going to black near the edges of the window. I'd use it such that the brighter a pixel is, the more likely a point for the voronoi tiling is to be placed there.